# CodeLite 16.0.0 Autocomplete Isn't Working

Tags: autocomplete, codelite

Hi all I've just started using CodeLite Version 16.0.0 . I was told by an instructor to set up autocomplete so that it should pop up after typing the first three letters. However, multiple times on this first program that the autocomplete list should have popped up failed to do so. In the included image, you'll see at the top that I was trying to get autocomplete to populate a list with **iostream** as one of the entries and that the list didn't show up after the first three letters were entered. Can anyone help me get this working correctly? I'm using CodeLite Version 16.0.0 on Windows 11. Thanks for all assistance!

[image: Can See iostream but no autocompletion after the first 3 letters entered]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an old version of CodeLite.
so you should:

- (Important) Upgrade to the latest `16.4.0` from [here](https://codelite.org/support.php)
- Windows system are always trickier to setup, so make sure you have a working MSYS environment as described [here](https://docs.codelite.org/build/mingw_builds/#prepare-a-working-environment)
- Last step: make sure that the [Language Server Plugin](https://docs.codelite.org/plugins/lsp/) is configured properly
- Build your project -> code completion should be working for you now

HTH,

Eran

Comment: Sounds legit, will have to try it when I get home from campus. Will hit the answer switch if it works out

Comment: Oh yeah now I remember I have 16.0.0 as it's the latest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by going to Plugins->Manage Plugins->Then enable checkboxes "LanguageServerPlugin" and "Word Completion"
Then restart CodeLite IDE

This is from CodeLite Version :17.8.0 but I think this should Work